# Kickstrap - Minimum libraries needed for Install

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013, installation, kickstrap

I'm trying to install Kickstrap right now, but I have a fairly terrible internet connection.

The docs pages tell me to download and install Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, but state that it's just for the libraries. Well, I'd like to know what libraries are necessary, and where I can get them, since an extraneous 6.3 gig download is going to take all day :(

Thanks in advance for anyone who knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel a bit dumb, but at the same time, I feel a bit confused by the documentation. I just went ahead and followed all instructions without Visual Studio and it worked out fine. So, yeah, ridiculously massive, unnecessary step ignored.

Comment: please accept your answer to avoid jamming up the system. Also, how is this related to bootstrapping?

Answer (score 0):

It says in the [Roots documentation](https://github.com/jenius/roots#installation), which is mentioned by the [Kickstrap documentation](http://getkickstrap.com/docs.html#/first-steps), that the only thing you need from Visual Studio is the [.NET Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40779)

Comment: Why does the documentation even mention installing Visual Studio Ultimate then, why not just link to the framework like you just did?